# Python Sql Alchemy - How to jsonify a class object result from a database query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, eve

Basically, I just want to json encode the results of my sql query.

```
x = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username = request.form['username'], password = request.form['password']).first()
  print vars(x)
return jsonify(x)

raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

TypeError: < User WashingtonGeorge> is not JSON serializable
```

Here is the result for the print vars(x)

```
{'_updated': None, 'username': u'WashingtonGeorge', 'password': u'Washington', '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7fd12a50c8d0>, 'firstname': u'George', 'lastname': u'Washington', '_created': None, 'fullname': u'George Washington', '_id': 1, 'email': u'WashingtonGeorge@yahoo.com'}
```

Comment: You need to serialize the results. look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask?rq=1

Comment: http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: To JSON serialize , here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171690/how-to-jsonify-objects-from-sqlalchemy/53519960#53519960

Answer (score 5):

You can use marshallow. Here is the example. define a `serializer.py` and put it beside your `main.py` file, and:

in    `serializer.py`

```
from marshmallow import Serializer

###### USER SERIALIZER #####
class UserSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ('username')
        # you can add any other member of class user in fields

#Return the user data in json format
def get_user_serialized(user):
    return UserSerializer(user).data
```

in your `main.py`

```
from .serializers import get_user_serialized
...
...
...

x = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username = request.form['username'], password = request.form['password']).first()

serialized = [get_user_serialized(item) for item in x]
res = jsonify(res=serialized)
return res
```

Comment: Here's a gist that is up to date with marshmallow 1.0: https://gist.github.com/sloria/aecc540db3a95fbbee2f

Answer (score 1):

With JSON serialize you can do that.

Look this: http://prschmid.blogspot.com/2012/12/json-serializing-sqlalchemy-objects.html

it work for me

Answer (score 0):

I assume the variable `'_updated'` & `'_created'` in your `class User` are of type DateTime. Datetime is not serilzable in jsonify. You can just convert your datetime variable into str. i.e. str(some_date_in_datetimeformat) might work. 
Also, `'_sa_instance_state'` which is of type sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState should be serializable.

**Update:**

jsonify is not able to serialize your object. The best solution is to define a function serialize() inside your class and use it to make the data serializable. So your class becomes,

```
class User(object):
    def serialize():
        return {
            '_id': 1,
            'username': u'WashingtonGeorge'
            'fullname': u'George Washington'
            # other fields that you need in the json 
        }
```

then at the place where you want to jsonify the data, just call.

```
jsonify(x.serialize())
```

Comment: I tried delecting the attributes which contained datetime fields and the method you suggested didn't work.        results = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username = request.form['username'], password = request.form['password']).first()
    del results._created
    del results._updated 
    print vars(results)
    return jsonify(results = results)

Comment: I updated my answer. This is a common problem with jsonify, and has been answered before on stackoverflow (See codegeek's comment on your question.)